# Convert all text to UPPERCASE in a Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet I'm sharing with others to collect some data. Each person is just (supposed to be) putting a single character in any of a range of cells.

How can I cause those cells to convert to uppercase?

Using `=UPPER()` in each cell would seem to be a non-starter, because it'll be overwritten by whatever they enter.

Comment: Could someone expand on this answer please? Specifically, when I have written and saved my script, how should I execute it on a given range of cells back in my Google Sheet?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a script that automatically converts input to upper case:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (typeof e.value != 'object') {
    e.range.setValue(e.value.toUpperCase());
  }
}
```

From the spreadsheet, go Extensions > Apps Script. Put the above code in the code window (replacing anything pre-filled there), and save.

---

If you wanted to enforce upper case **and** single-character entries, then data validation could be used, with custom formula

```
=regexmatch(A1,"^[A-Z]$")
```

This is assuming the upper left corner of the range is A1, and that you expect letters of Latin alphabet.  The regular expression `^[A-Z]$` means: beginning of string; single character in the range A-Z; end of string.

Comment: Could someone expand on this answer please? Specifically, when I have written and saved my script, how should I execute it on a given range of cells back in my Google Sheet?

Comment: @tomh this script work for a whole spreadsheet. did you consider to use `=ARRAYFORMULA(UPPER(A:Z)` ?

Comment: Hi - I'm asking for the step by step process to take the script and apply it to a range of highlighted cells in a sheet. Ideally from a menu command

Comment: @tomh did you get this script workin' ?

Comment: No. I used an add-on called Cases to achieve the same effect.  But I'd like to know how to apply a script to a series of cells in a sheet, and I think it would be a useful answer on this post.

Comment: @tomh like I mentioned already... this script works on a whole sheet, not on a specified range. if you still want it I can guide you how to get this script working

Comment: I have saved this, but it does not execute on save

Answer (score 1):

This is [What you want](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/wGMy5UYJLWg/UqW2vsdlAQAJ).

Just change this line in the script...

**ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')**

...to this...

**ui.createMenu('Case Change')**

... for your own sake.

Comment: Posts on this site should be self contained. Please add the most relevant parts of the referred resource.

Comment: @Rubén, this post is three-and-a-half years old. In fact, it may have even been my very first reply post here on Stack. And your answer from back then was already selected as "Best Answer," so changing this secondary post now seems moot. (It'd be easier to delete it.) Is there a reason you're going back through posts from this long ago? At any rate, I hope you find my current posts more to your liking.

Comment: Someone referred this post in a suggested edit to the accepted answer suggesting that the link included here has a good solution. P.S. I have not posted an answer here, I only made an slight edit to the accepted answer.