# Conditionally substitute cell contents with Unicode characters

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

Is it possible to conditionally substitute a cells **contents**, with a Unicode character i.e. rather than colouring all '1' cells green, swap the '1' for another character instead?

Specifically, I want to exchange integers for '[Harvey Balls](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvey_Balls)'.

For example, I have:

```
A | B | C | D

X | 1 | 2 | 1

Y | 2 | 4 | 1

Z | 3 | 2 | 4
```

I'd like the same table formatted as below (without duplication):

```
A | B | C | D

X | ◔ | ◕ | ◔

Y | ● | ● | ◔

X | ◕ | ◕ | ●
```

If it's any help, the substitute rule I have so far is: `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(F11, "0", char(9675)),"1", char(9684)), "2", char(9681)), "3", char(9685)), "4", char(9679))`

I've also added the above tests to a publicly availably [Google spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18eU2MwOCgyaeMymvN-oTbjnkyuRM8KuMcYhUKtiSZkY/edit?usp=sharing).

I don't mind - but would like to avoid - a duplicate column or table. But the latter option (typing values in a second sheet, that update renders first sheet with unicode characters) seems to be the only option to me...

Comment: There is no conditional formatting with Harvey balls in Google Sheets (like Excel has). So the only way to have ◔ shown in place of 1 is to _replace_ 1 with ◔ , in which case the number is gone; in particular you will not be able to calculate with this data. Is this acceptable?

Comment: @NormalHuman I don't need to run calculations but I do want it to update automatically. Would your technique still work if I went back and changed what was a 1, to a 2? If so, that's what I'm after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is similar in spirit to [Convert all text to UPPERCASE in a Google Spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/86751), so a similar script solution can be used. This script automatically replaces 0-4 by corresponding Harvey Balls in the spreadsheet to which it's bound. (It does not affect pre-existing cells, since it's triggered by edits.)

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var n = parseInt(e.value, 10);
  if (n == e.value && n >= 0 && n <= 4) {
    e.range.setValue(['○', '◔', '◑', '◕', '●'][n]);
  }
}
```

The check `n == e.value` is to avoid converting fractional values like 2.3.

One can also extend the condition with something like

```
&& SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName() == 'MySheet'
```

to restrict the automatic replacement to a particular sheet.