# Changing the text of an entire column to uppercase

Tags: google-sheets

I want Google spreadsheets to automatically uppercase text inputted into a cell.

I'm using the following code and receiving circular dependency errors:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(UPPER(C5:C))
```

I'm inputting text into column C

Answer (score -2):

In would clearly look into this [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/86753) as a starting point.

Scripts will be your holy grail with Google Apps!