# How can I change the case of text in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

Something that would be able to

coNverT WeiRD caPS -> Convert Weird Caps

Answer (score 3):

Welp found it. Read the docs.

The formulas are

`=upper()`
`=lower()`
`=proper()`

There is also this answer if you need something fancy because the cells will be overwritten. [Convert all text to UPPERCASE in a Google Spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/86751/convert-all-text-to-uppercase-in-a-google-spreadsheet)

But the formulas work great.

Answer (score 0):

In the case Joshua Dance's answer above isn't clear enough,

1. On an empty cell, type `=proper(`. (Yes, without the close-parenthesis)
2. Click on the cell containing the text you want to change to Proper Case (a.k.a Title Case.)
3. Hit Enter. (You'll see the result in the previously empty cell.)